# Output javascript array in a list item, then clicking on either of them will show a whole item in another dic

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So I have to finish a task, and I'm a total javascript/jquery newb!
My problem is this:

We need to have several list items, outputed from a javascript. The list itsm contains only the tile. 
Then when the use clicks on either of those list items, the full info appears somewhere else on the page, with more details.

I have to work with this:

```
var data={
    "news":[
        {
            "id":"0",
            "title":"Find the best deals",
            "sub":"Featured Story",
            "text":"0 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi porttitor mattis elementum. Duis scelerisque sit amet sem ac lacinia. Aenean ut nisl viverra, scelerisque lectus eget, ullamcorper leo. Ut quis mi mi. Donec vestibulum tellus sed ipsum sodales pharetra. <br/><br/>Praesent sit amet dui luctus, mollis lacus nec, tincidunt magna. Nulla laoreet mauris at nisl dictum, ut ullamcorper magna rhoncus. Suspendisse potenti. Suspendisse quis tincidunt odio, non tristique turpis. Suspendisse consequat sapien vitae ultrices scelerisque. Pellentesque luctus magna laoreet orci consequat fermentum.<br/><br/>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi porttitor mattis elementum. Duis scelerisque sit amet sem ac lacinia. Aenean ut nisl viverra, scelerisque lectus eget, ullamcorper leo. Ut quis mi mi. Donec vestibulum tellus sed ipsum sodales pharetra. <br/><br/>Praesent sit amet dui luctus, mollis lacus nec, tincidunt magna. Nulla laoreet mauris at nisl dictum, ut ullamcorper magna rhoncus. Suspendisse potenti. Suspendisse quis tincidunt odio, non tristique turpis. Suspendisse consequat sapien vitae ultrices scelerisque. Pellentesque luctus magna laoreet orci consequat fermentum.<br/><br/>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi porttitor mattis elementum. Duis scelerisque sit amet sem ac lacinia. Aenean ut nisl viverra, scelerisque lectus eget, ullamcorper leo. Ut quis mi mi. Donec vestibulum tellus sed ipsum sodales pharetra. <br/><br/>Praesent sit amet dui luctus, mollis lacus nec, tincidunt magna. Nulla laoreet mauris at nisl dictum, ut ullamcorper magna rhoncus. Suspendisse potenti. Suspendisse quis tincidunt odio, non tristique turpis. Suspendisse consequat sapien vitae ultrices scelerisque. Pellentesque luctus magna laoreet orci consequat fermentum.<br/><br/>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi porttitor mattis elementum. Duis scelerisque sit amet sem ac lacinia. Aenean ut nisl viverra, scelerisque lectus eget, ullamcorper leo. Ut quis mi mi. Donec vestibulum tellus sed ipsum sodales pharetra. <br/><br/>Praesent sit amet dui luctus, mollis lacus nec, tincidunt magna. Nulla laoreet mauris at nisl dictum, ut ullamcorper magna rhoncus. Suspendisse potenti. Suspendisse quis tincidunt odio, non tristique turpis. Suspendisse consequat sapien vitae ultrices scelerisque. Pellentesque luctus magna laoreet orci consequat fermentum.",
            "image":"images\/home_img_4.jpg",
            "link":"#NEWS_0",
        },
        {
            "id":"1",
            "title":"No one likes the grudge",
            "sub":"Featured Story 1",
            "text":"1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi porttitor mattis elementum. Duis scelerisque sit amet sem ac lacinia. Aenean ut nisl viverra, scelerisque lectus eget, ullamcorper leo. Ut quis mi mi. Donec vestibulum tellus sed ipsum sodales pharetra. <br/><br/>Praesent sit amet dui luctus, mollis lacus nec, tincidunt magna. Nulla laoreet mauris at nisl dictum, ut ullamcorper magna rhoncus. Suspendisse potenti. Suspendisse quis tincidunt odio, non tristique turpis. Suspendisse consequat sapien vitae ultrices scelerisque. Pellentesque luctus magna laoreet orci consequat fermentum.<br/><br/>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi porttitor mattis elementum. Duis scelerisque sit amet sem ac lacinia. Aenean ut nisl viverra, scelerisque lectus eget, ullamcorper leo. Ut quis mi mi. Donec vestibulum tellus sed ipsum sodales pharetra. <br/><br/>Praesent sit amet dui luctus, mollis lacus nec, tincidunt magna. Nulla laoreet mauris at nisl dictum, ut ullamcorper magna rhoncus. Suspendisse potenti. Suspendisse quis tincidunt odio, non tristique turpis. Suspendisse consequat sapien vitae ultrices scelerisque. Pellentesque luctus magna laoreet orci consequat fermentum.<br/><br/>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi porttitor mattis elementum. Duis scelerisque sit amet sem ac lacinia. Aenean ut nisl viverra, scelerisque lectus eget, ullamcorper leo. Ut quis mi mi. Donec vestibulum tellus sed ipsum sodales pharetra. <br/><br/>Praesent sit amet dui luctus, mollis lacus nec, tincidunt magna. Nulla laoreet mauris at nisl dictum, ut ullamcorper magna rhoncus. Suspendisse potenti. Suspendisse quis tincidunt odio, non tristique turpis. Suspendisse consequat sapien vitae ultrices scelerisque. Pellentesque luctus magna laoreet orci consequat fermentum.<br/><br/>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi porttitor mattis elementum. Duis scelerisque sit amet sem ac lacinia. Aenean ut nisl viverra, scelerisque lectus eget, ullamcorper leo. Ut quis mi mi. Donec vestibulum tellus sed ipsum sodales pharetra. <br/><br/>Praesent sit amet dui luctus, mollis lacus nec, tincidunt magna. Nulla laoreet mauris at nisl dictum, ut ullamcorper magna rhoncus. Suspendisse potenti. Suspendisse quis tincidunt odio, non tristique turpis. Suspendisse consequat sapien vitae ultrices scelerisque. Pellentesque luctus magna laoreet orci consequat fermentum.",
            "image":"images\/home_img_4.jpg",
            "link":"#NEWS_1",
        },
        {
            "id":"2",
            "title":"Story time is on!",
            "sub":"Featured Story2",
            "text":"2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi porttitor mattis elementum. Duis scelerisque sit amet sem ac lacinia. Aenean ut nisl viverra, scelerisque lectus eget, ullamcorper leo. Ut quis mi mi. Donec vestibulum tellus sed ipsum sodales pharetra. <br/><br/>Praesent sit amet dui luctus, mollis lacus nec, tincidunt magna. Nulla laoreet mauris at nisl dictum, ut ullamcorper magna rhoncus. Suspendisse potenti. Suspendisse quis tincidunt odio, non tristique turpis. Suspendisse consequat sapien vitae ultrices scelerisque. Pellentesque luctus magna laoreet orci consequat fermentum.<br/><br/>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi porttitor mattis elementum. Duis scelerisque sit amet sem ac lacinia. Aenean ut nisl viverra, scelerisque lectus eget, ullamcorper leo. Ut quis mi mi. Donec vestibulum tellus sed ipsum sodales pharetra. <br/><br/>Praesent sit amet dui luctus, mollis lacus nec, tincidunt magna. Nulla laoreet mauris at nisl dictum, ut ullamcorper magna rhoncus. Suspendisse potenti. Suspendisse quis tincidunt odio, non tristique turpis. Suspendisse consequat sapien vitae ultrices scelerisque. Pellentesque luctus magna laoreet orci consequat fermentum.<br/><br/>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi porttitor mattis elementum. Duis scelerisque sit amet sem ac lacinia. Aenean ut nisl viverra, scelerisque lectus eget, ullamcorper leo. Ut quis mi mi. Donec vestibulum tellus sed ipsum sodales pharetra. <br/><br/>Praesent sit amet dui luctus, mollis lacus nec, tincidunt magna. Nulla laoreet mauris at nisl dictum, ut ullamcorper magna rhoncus. Suspendisse potenti. Suspendisse quis tincidunt odio, non tristique turpis. Suspendisse consequat sapien vitae ultrices scelerisque. Pellentesque luctus magna laoreet orci consequat fermentum.<br/><br/>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi porttitor mattis elementum. Duis scelerisque sit amet sem ac lacinia. Aenean ut nisl viverra, scelerisque lectus eget, ullamcorper leo. Ut quis mi mi. Donec vestibulum tellus sed ipsum sodales pharetra. <br/><br/>Praesent sit amet dui luctus, mollis lacus nec, tincidunt magna. Nulla laoreet mauris at nisl dictum, ut ullamcorper magna rhoncus. Suspendisse potenti. Suspendisse quis tincidunt odio, non tristique turpis. Suspendisse consequat sapien vitae ultrices scelerisque. Pellentesque luctus magna laoreet orci consequat fermentum.",
            "image":"images\/home_img_4.jpg",
            "link":"#NEWS_2",
        },

    ]
}
```

Also heres a better example for what im looking for:
[jsfindle](http://jsfiddle.net/j9QEM/)

Thanks!
George

Comment: You should share with us your JavaScript and we cold try to help you with your errors. But you shouldn't wait for us solving your task!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When populating the UL list add an attribute "data-item" to the LI(s), 
give it the value of the index of that item in the data array.

```
<ul class="mini-feed">
    <li class="title" data-item="0">Test title</li>
    <li class="title" data-item="1">Test title 1</li>
    <li class="title" data-item="2">Test title 2</li>
    <li class="title" data-item="3">Test title 3</li>
    <li class="title" data-item="4">Test title 4</li>
</ul>
```

also give the elements in the display section IDs:

```
<div class="">
    <img id="image" src="" class="image" />
    <h1 id="title" class="title">Test title</h1>
    <span id="body" class="sub">some tagline</span>
</div>
```

then add the following javascript (considering you are using jQuery)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.title').click(function(){
  var itemIndex = $(this).data('item');
  popItemToScreen(data.news[itemIndex]);
 });
});

function popItemToScreen(dataItem){
 $('#image').src = dataItem.image;
 $('#title').html(dataItem.title);
 $('#body').html(dataItem.text);
}
```

this should do the trick

Comment: Thanks so much guys! Finally figured it out! YAY

Comment: Btw, I'm trying to do the same thing but on another array. The wierd thing is that is seems that the arrays get mixed up. Any ideeas?

Answer (score 1):

**Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/j9QEM/11/

```
<ul id="mylist">
    <li data-id="0">Title 1</li>
    <li data-id="1">Title 2</li>
    <li data-id="2">Title 3</li>
</ul>

<div id="content"></div>

<script>
    /**
     * get the data-index="" value and
     * use it's id as an index to pick 
     * a particular item from the data[] array
     * 
     * .html() populates #content with the given
     * .text.
    **/
    $('#mylist li').on('click', function() {
         $('#content').html( data.news[$(this).data('id')].text );
    });
</script>
```

Within your comments, you mentioned about loading the page with Id in mind, you could after page load:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
       //This will pre-load the Array's 3rd news piece.
       $('#content').html( data.news[2].text );
    });
</script>
```

Comment: yeah somewhere around here, but id like to already have a element on the page present when it starts, and also it doesnt work properly; I clik a couple of times to move around and it doensnt seem to work

Comment: nevermind, I figured it out, but would like to have a element already there on the page presenent in div id="content"

Comment: Edited my answer, and apologises, I spotted my mistake on the Fiddle =)

Comment: Yeah works that way, but also would need more files to div id="content", not only the text, but the sub and the image src

Comment: In that case Jad A. Jabbour is probably the right person to upvote, he's taken his time to write actual placeholders for each of those other fields =)